# Not sure how to return the value of an object

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, return, undefined

I want to return the password of a user's account if they have a password. If not I want it to return undefined.

EDIT: The user is an account holder for a website, the password is the password to gain entry to their account.

My attempt:

```
function retrievePassword(user) {
    if (user = password) {
    return password;
} else {
    return '';
}}
```

I believe my problem lies in the secound line. I want to say if the user CONTAINS or HAS or POSSESES a password, then return it. I am sure that user = password is not communicating that, but I haven't a clue how you are supposed to say that.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator?

Comment: `if (user.password)`, if you are talking about object properties?

Comment: There is a problem with `if (user = password)`; `=` is an assignment statement, not an equality check.

Comment: "*If not I want it to return undefined.*" - do you refer to the function or to the expression? Because the function does never return `undefined`.

Comment: the in operator appears to be what I am looking for however I have just tried it to no avail. This is my attempt:

Comment: if ('password' in user === true) {
    return password;
}   else {
    return '';
}}

Comment: @kylehink97 Please [edit] your post and clarify your attempts. What exactly is `user`? What exactly is `password`? How exactly is `retrievePassword` used?

Comment: Please [edit] your post. We need the descriptions in terms of _code_.